# c++ Pointer Being Freed Was not Allocated

Tags: c++, memory, dynamic, operator-overloading

Hello I'm trying to delete my dynamic memory within my class but I am getting the following error :

```
a.out(2830) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fb38a4039c0: pointer being freed was not allocated
```

*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Abort trap: 6

I think is has something to do with my overloaded  "=" operator not accessing my class directly "&".

```
class Polynomial{
    public:
        //Constructors / Destructors
        Polynomial();
        Polynomial(int tempNum, int * tempPoly);
        ~Polynomial();

        //Member Functions & Operator overloading
        //Addition
        Polynomial operator+(Polynomial& Poly);
        //Subtraction
        Polynomial operator-(Polynomial& Poly);
        //Multiplication
        Polynomial operator*(Polynomial& Poly);
        //Assignment
        Polynomial operator=(Polynomial Poly);

        //Insertion
        friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, Polynomial& Poly);
        //Extraction
        friend istream& operator>>(istream& is, Polynomial& Poly);

    private:
        //Data Members
        //Int array (degree of polynomial + 1)
        int * poly;
        int polyNum;
};


Implementation: 

Polynomial::Polynomial(){
    polyNum = 0;
}

Polynomial::~Polynomial(){
    //Delete Dynamic Memory
    delete [] poly;
}

Polynomial::Polynomial(int tempNum, int *tempPoly){

    poly = new int[tempNum+1];

    polyNum = tempNum;

    for (int i=0; i < tempNum; i++) {
        poly[i] = tempPoly[i];
    }
}

//Addition
Polynomial Polynomial::operator+(Polynomial &Poly){
    Polynomial temp;

    if(polyNum > Poly.polyNum){
        temp.polyNum = polyNum;
    }
    else{
        temp.polyNum = Poly.polyNum;
    }

    temp.poly = new int[temp.polyNum + 1];

    for(int i=0; i < temp.polyNum; i++){
        temp.poly[i] = Poly.poly[i] + poly[i];
    }

    return (temp);
}

//Subtraction
Polynomial Polynomial::operator-(Polynomial& Poly){
    Polynomial temp;

    if(polyNum > Poly.polyNum){
        temp.polyNum = polyNum;
    }
    else{
        temp.polyNum = Poly.polyNum;
    }

    temp.poly = new int[temp.polyNum + 1];

    for(int i=0; i < temp.polyNum; i++){
        temp.poly[i] = poly[i] - Poly.poly[i];
    }

    return (temp);
}

//Multiplication
Polynomial Polynomial::operator*(Polynomial& Poly){

    Polynomial temp;

    //make coefficient array
    temp.polyNum = (polyNum + Poly.polyNum) - 1;

    temp.poly = new int [temp.polyNum];

    for (int i = 0; i < temp.polyNum; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < Poly.polyNum; j++){
            temp.poly[i+j] += poly[i] * Poly.poly[j];
        }
    }

    return temp;
}

//Assignment
Polynomial Polynomial::operator=(Polynomial Poly){

    polyNum = Poly.polyNum;

    poly = new int[polyNum+1];

    for (int i=0; i < polyNum; i++) {
        poly[i] = Poly.poly[i];
    }

    return *this;
}

//Insertion
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, Polynomial& Poly){

    for (int i=0; i < Poly.polyNum; i++) {
        os << Poly.poly[i] << " x^" << i;

        if(i != Poly.polyNum - 1){
            os << " + ";
        }
    }

    return os;
}

//Extraction
istream& operator>>(istream& is, Polynomial& Poly){

    int numP = 0;
    int * tempP;

    is >> numP;

    tempP = new int [numP+1];

    for (int i=0; i < numP; i++) {
        is >> tempP[i];
    }

    Poly.polyNum = numP;

    Poly.poly = new int[Poly.polyNum +1];

    for (int i=0; i < Poly.polyNum; i++) {
        Poly.poly[i] = tempP[i];
    }

    delete [] tempP;

    return is;
}
```

Main

```
int main(){

// Input Polynomial #1 (P1)
cout << "Input polynominal p1: " << endl;
Polynomial P1;
cin >> P1;

// Output Polynominal
cout << "p1(x) = " << P1 << '\n' << endl;

// Input Polynomial #2 (P2)
cout << "Input polynominal p2: " << endl;
Polynomial P2;
cin >> P2;

// Output Polynominal
cout << "p2(x) = " << P2 << '\n' << endl;

// Copy P2 to P3 and output P3
Polynomial P3;
P3 = P2;
cout << "Copy p2 to p3, p3(x) = " << P3 << '\n' << endl;

// Add P1 to P2 and output to P3
Polynomial P4;
P4 = P1 + P2;
cout << "p3(x) = p1(x) + p2(x) = " << P4 << '\n' << endl;

// Subtract P1 from P2 and output to P3
Polynomial P5;
P5 = P1 - P2;
cout << "p3(x) = p1(x) - p2(x) = " << P5 << '\n' << endl;

// Subtract P2 from P1 and output to P3
Polynomial P6;
P6 = P2 - P1;
cout << "p3(x) = p2(x) - p1(x) = " << P6 << '\n' << endl;

// Multiply P1 by P2 and output to P3
Polynomial P7;
P7 = P1 * P2;
cout << "p3(x) = p1(x) * p2(x) = " << P7 << '\n' << endl;

return 0;
```

}

Comment: Can you post an example program that causes the error? I see a leak on the = operator.

Comment: @nmenezes i put my main program up there for you

Comment: Three things: Second is that you allocate `polyNum+1` but you only use `polyNum` entries in the allocated array. Second is that in the assignment operator you do not free the existing array if you have one, leading to a memory leak. Thirdly, why not use e.g. `std::vector` so you don't have to worry about these things?

Comment: just use `std::vector<int>` instead of `poly` and `polynum`. Saves you a lot of pain.

Comment: A fourth thing, the assignment operator should return a _reference_, not a _copy_ like you do now.

Comment: Rule #1: Don't use `new`. Rule #2. When you use `new`, always remember the [Rule of Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Polynomial::Polynomial(){
    polyNum = 0;
}
Polynomial::~Polynomial(){
    //Delete Dynamic Memory
    delete [] poly;           // <-- bug
}
```

here is a bug for you: poly is not initialised in the default ctor, but deleted in the dtor.

*EDIT*

really you should use a `std::vector<int>`:

```
class polynomial
{
  std::vector<int> _pol;       
public:
  size_t degree() const { return _pol.empty()? 0 : _pol.size() - 1; }
  polynomial() = default;                   // could be omitted (compiler generated anyway)
  polynomial(polynomial const&) = default;  // ----
  /// evaluate polynomial
  template<typename T>
  T operator() (T const&x) const
  {
    T y(0);
    T p(1);
    for(auto i : _pol) {
      y += *i * p;
      p *= x;
    }
    return y;
  }
  polynomial& operator+=(polynomial const&other)
  {
    auto j = other._pol.begin();
    for(auto i = _pol.begin(); i!=_pol.end() && j!=other._pol.end(); ++i,++j)
      *i += *j;
    for(; j != other._pol.end(); ++j)
      _pol.push_back(*j);
    return*this;
  }
  polynomial operator+(polynomial const&other) const
  {
    polynomial _p(*this);
    return _p += other;           
  }
  // etc
};
```

You should also implement the move ctor and operator appropriately so that in expressions like `polynomial sum = a+b;` no re-allocation of memory is required when copying a temporary.

Comment: ok so what should i do? if i set the amount of poly somewhere else?

Answer (score 4):

You have a default constructor (which has a bug) and assignment operator, but you also need to define a copy constructor. If you don't, each copy of a `Polynomial` gets the same pointer for `poly` that the one it was copied from has, and you deallocate the same pointer each time one of those copies is destroyed. The second time this happens, you call `delete[]` on a pointer that was already `delete[]`ed, causing this error.

Your copy constructor should look something like this

```
Polynomial::Polynomial(const Polynomial& rhs) : poly(new int[rhs.polynum]), polynum(rhs.polynum) {
    std::copy(rhs.poly, rhs.poly + polynum, poly);
}
```

That said, if you use `std::vector` you wouldn't have to have either an assignment operator or a copy constructor, and not even a separate variable to keep track of how many `poly`s you have, so I recommend doing that.

You also need to fix your default constructor; at least set `poly` to `nullptr` so that you don't `delete[]` an uninitialised pointer in your destructor.

Comment: Ok i need this to be explained a bit further :( can you show me some code ?

Comment: @DanielDC did you still need explanation or did Walter's answer clarify it?